# Please display bigger tags on top of questions instead of small ones at the bottom

Tags: feature-request, tags

While hunting stack overflow for questions to answer, I figured out it would probably be easier to quickly see the questions you might be interested in if the tags were bigger and clearer.

Tags are faster to read than question titles, and it is quite hard to quickly figure out what topic the question is about just by reading the title.

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't encouraging better titles be a more straightforward solution to your dilemma?

A lot of us +2k-rep users try to fix up titles but we can't get them all. Users who mess up titles are also very likely to mistag their questions, too. At least, in my experience this seems to be the case. Having bigger tags isn't going to help you when the SQL question is tagged `php, apache, newbie, vampire, help`.

Comment: Indeed. Like the ones who just type their title back into the tag fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your interesting tags for the tags you're interested in, then they will highlight and stand-out.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want it...This will reverse the order of your tags/titles, and increase the font-size a bit on the tags to make them "pop" out a bit more. Just install greasemonkey, and you'll be up and running.

```
(function(){
  function GM_wait() {
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
      window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
    } else { 
      $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); 
    }
  }
  GM_wait();
  function letsJQuery() {

    $("div.summary").each(function(){
        $(this).find("div.tags").css({"float":"none","font-size":"14px","margin":"0px 0px 5px 0px"})
            .insertBefore($(this).find("h3"));
    });

  }
})();
```